# Can Jenkins Rake working directory use variables

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, rake, jenkins-plugins

In jenkins, I am trying to run a Rake task that is in a sub folder
Ideally I would like to specify the "Rake working directory" property using a variable that I load from a properties file (created in a previous step and loaded using the EnvInject plugin).

I am aiming for a job setup of something like this:

[image]

However, when I try to run this job, I get the error

```
FATAL: rake execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "rake.bat" 
(in directory "d:\jenkins\workspace\ln-job-felix-web-master-configure\Build\Projects\$RAKE_PROJECT_NAME"): 
CreateProcess error=267, The directory name is invalid
```

When I fill in the Rake working directory with a hard coded value it works.
The echo commands output the correct RAKE_PROJECT_NAME value from the build.properties file.

Setup:

- Jenkins: 1.611
- Environment Injector Plugin: 1.91.3
- Rake Plugin: 1.8.0
- Running on a Windows 2012 slave server

Does anyone have any ideas of how to use a variable in the Rake working directory?

Thanks for any help

Saan

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with %RAKE_PROJECT_NAME% or ${RAKE_PROJECT_NAME}?

Comment: That means the Rake build step doesn't manage the Jenkins environment variables. In the Windows batch command step, you can try to set a system environment variable with the SETX command.